# iOS SWIFT - Detect peripheral turning off from central

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Is there any way from the Central app to detect when a peripheral for example runs out of power and consequently disconnects?

I tried using this:
`func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) { bleCentralManagerDelegate?.disconnectFromDeviceBLEResult(result: true)}`

But this event gets called only if the peripheral requests an actual disconnection, and does NOT get called if the peripheral randomly turns off.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't. A generic BLE disconnection usually has the "disconnection reason" as part of the disconnection event (see [this](https://www.argenox.com/blog/understanding-ble-disconnections/)), but this is not reliable and in any case CoreBluetooth does not directly expose this. I say "not directly expose this" because you do get the **error**  parameter as part of the event, but this is not a direct mapping to the actual disconnection reason happening on the stack.

The only workaround you can do is if you add the intelligence yourself. In other words, when the peripheral is about to turn off or when it has very low battery, it can send that information to the central (via a GATT write/notification) to let it know that it is about to disconnect because the battery is low.

Have a look at the links below for more information:-

- [Understanding BLE disconnections](https://www.argenox.com/blog/understanding-ble-disconnections/)
- [CoreBluetooth CBError](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cberror?language=objc)

Comment: Thanks! But what if i send a read characteristic request and the peripheral has been turned off? At this point i dont get any event fired and i also dont get any sort of error? Any way of catching this? My objective here is that if a peripheral turns off and the central performs a characteristic read, i dont get any sort of response or error from any event.
EDIT: more specifically: Connection - peripheral disconnection - characteristic read from central to peripheral - no info about any error (the peripheral is not available anymore)???
~Zorro

Comment: I meant that you add this intelligence on the peripheral side and not on the central side. In other words, before running out of battery, the peripheral needs to tell the central device (via a notification maybe) that it is about to die. This way, the central is aware that when the communication is lost with the peripheral then it is because the device ran out of battery. I know this is not an ideal solution but just a workaround. There is no way of catching this from the central side if the peripheral switched off without letting the central know that its battery is low.

Comment: Perfect thanks; but what about the read characteristic? I dont get any error if i try to read something from a peripheral that was switched off?

Comment: The read operation will definitely fail because there wont be an active connection to read the data from if the device is switched off

Comment: Thanks. Right now i dont get any response or anything to show that the read characteristic failed. No event is thrown. If anyone has this issue, my workaround will be to implement a timeout for a keepalive request. I'll implement a keepalive that will run every 30 seconds; when the keepalive request starts, if i dont get any answer after 5 seconds i'll throw an error myself

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    let cState = central.state
    
    switch cState {
    case .unknown:
      if ( preLogLevel == "LOGLEVEL" ) {
        CSVfuncs.writeLog(">>BT central.state is .unknown")
      }
      
    case .resetting:
      if ( preLogLevel == "LOGLEVEL" ) {
        CSVfuncs.writeLog(">>BT central.state is .resetting")
      }
      
    case .unsupported:
      if ( preLogLevel == "LOGLEVEL" ) {
        CSVfuncs.writeLog(">>BT central.state is .unsupported")
      }
      
    case .unauthorized:
      if ( preLogLevel == "LOGLEVEL" ) {
        CSVfuncs.writeLog(">>BT central.state is .unauthorized")
      }
      
    case .poweredOff:
      if ( preLogLevel == "LOGLEVEL" ) {
        CSVfuncs.writeLog(">>BT central.state is .poweredOff")
      }
      
    case .poweredOn:
      if ( preLogLevel == "LOGLEVEL" ) {
        CSVfuncs.writeLog(">>BT central.state is .poweredOn")
      }
      centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: servicesInterested)
      
    @unknown default:
      if ( preLogLevel == "LOGLEVEL" ) {
        CSVfuncs.writeLog(">>BT central.state is Unknown Default")
      }
      break
    // unknown default
    }
  }
```

Comment: No, i have this method already implemented and it works fine for most cases; however if the peripheral turns off this event doesnt get called
~Zorro